.Net Maui NLog not getting all log files
We have the following code:
  private async Task GetLogsAndWrite()
        {
        _logger.Flush();

        var logFiles = Directory.GetFiles(AppConstants.NLogDefaultPath);

        var logs = new List<string>();
        foreach (var log in logFiles)
        {
            logs.Add(await File.ReadAllTextAsync(log));
        }

        if (logs is not null && logs.Any())
        {
            foreach (var log in logs)
            {
                var logFileName = ("MyLog" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH_mm_ss")).Replace(" ", "") + ".txt";
                WriteToFile(log, logFileName);
            }
        }

    }

So the challenge I am facing is that when the log files upload - I am not getting all the data.  I know this for a fact because one of the last things logged in the app before the logs are uploaded - is that the log files are being uploaded.
An interesting thing is that, if I keep trying to upload -- after a period of time (at least 5-10 minutes) an additional log file is found on the device which contains the most recent data (i.e. the data I was missing).  That additional file is then included in the upload and I then have all the information.
How can I force NLog / Android / Maui to basically close everything and send ALL the data / log files?
It is very spotty to replicate but here is what I just did that replicated the challenge:
I ran my application yesterday and did a few things that got logged.  I closed the application.  Today, I started the application again, and performed some actions that are logged.  Then I attempted to upload the logs and I did not get the information from today.  Only the information from yesterday.
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.
UPDATE:
I added
LogManager.Shutdown();

to our code but it made no difference.  So the challenge seems to be when the app changes days.  So this morning - again, I went in, launched the app - performed some tasks and then attempted to upload the logs.  The only logs I got had entries dated from the previous day and nothing from the current day.
I still need some what to force NLog to write everything to files before I upload the log files which it appears to not be doing.

try using Shutdown instead of Flush

What is _logger.Flush(); ? Maybe try NLog.LogManager.Flush() before collecting files.

sorry - _logger.flush is the instance of the NLog.logmanager.  It does call           LogManager.Flush();

When calling NLog.LogManager.Flush() then it requests the FileStream to flush to disc, When calling NLog.LogManager.Shutdown() then one also flushes the FileStream, and then closes the FileStream. It doesn't sound like a NLog issue, but something with operating-system filesystem together with FileStream and File.ReadAllTextAsync.

Well the weird thing is that the data for the second day appears to be in separate file that does not seem to be found for about 30 minutes to an hour after I upload the first set of logs.

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Targets.MauiLog/issues/30

@RolfKristensen - Yeah - I opened that ticket also.
